# What is going on with scope in this beginners Python program?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, scope, integer

I'm a fairly experienced C# programmer taking a look at Python. I'm working from a book called Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python. Chapter two features this game...

```
# This is a Guess the Number game.
import random

# guessesTaken = 0

print ("Hello! What is your name?")
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1,10)
print("Well, " + myName + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10.")

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print ("Take a guess.") # Four spaces in front of "print"
    guess = input()
    guess = int (guess)

    testNumber = 5

    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low.") # Eight spaces in front of "print"

    if guess > number:
        print ("Your guess is too high.")

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken + 1)
    print ("Good job, " + myName + "! You guessed my number in " + guessesTaken + " guesses!")

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print ("Nope. The number I was thinking of was " + number + ".")

testNumber = str(testNumber)
print (testNumber)
```

I was a little confused about the guessesTaken variable, so I commented out it's instantiation line - and was surprised to find the code still behaved as normal.

In C#, I would expect guessesTaken in the For declaration to be out of scope for the rest of the program. However, later uses of the variable have no problem accessing the number in question.

To test this, I added the variable 'testNumber' within the For block and assigned it '5'. Sure enough, attempting to print the number outside of it's scope just works...!

I'm a little rusty with programming, but this is still a bit confusing to me - is the For loop not considered a different scope to the block surrounding it? [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) seems to suggest otherwise, but I guess it could be that For loops in Python are considered in scope with their surroundings.

Just seems a bit weird. Can anybody put me right here? I'll get back into C# to test this in that language later, but any responses now would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for guessesTaken in range(6):` creates the variable `guessesTaken` without you needing to explicitly do it, that is why the following code would also work (results in 9):

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    pass
print(x)
```

However, this would result in a `NameError`:

```
print(x)
for x in range(0, 10):
    pass
```

This is likely hidden away somewhere in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#for-statements).

The reason you can access `testNumber` is that it's assigned [local scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) by default; unless it's explicitly set, which in your code, happens to be local to the entire script. The for loop is not considered to be in a different [scope](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=scope#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I'd figured guessesTaken was also being declared in the for loop - but that seems... odd to me. I'll take a look at your docs, thank you.